# I Know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ Diverges, but what is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

We know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges since it is a harmonic series. However, I was recently working on a homework problem where I was given to find if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ converges. I found that it does converge, but I wanted to go further than just this. I was attempting to find what this sum was. I rechecked my work multiple times, and I know for sure that the sum does converge. How would I go about finding what the sum is for:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Take the geometric sequence
$$\frac 1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}x^n,\quad\text{for } |x|<1.$$

Now, integrate both sides.  You can integrate the right hand side term by term.  You should see something familiar.

Comment: But this only gives something legit under the restriction that $\lvert x\rvert <1$. As in the other answer, for the final step you need to invoke [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem), which is not a trivial step.

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\log(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}n$$
for $\vert x \vert <1$ and $x=1$.
Plug in $x=1$, to obtain the value of the expression.

Comment: That requires a little bit more arguing. This is not clear that you can just "plug in" $x=1$, when the radius of convergence of the series is actually $1$... you need to call in [some theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem) for that.

Comment: @ClementC. The interval of convergence is $(-1,1]$.   And that is trivially obvious since the alternating series is monotonically decreasing.

Comment: All I am saying is that, no matter easy to show it, it is not "obvious": there *is* something to at least acknowledge. Failing to say there is something to argue may lead the OP (or the reader) to think one can plug in any $x$...

Comment: @ClementC. What I have written is a true statement and in fact is true even when $x \in \mathbb{C}$ and lies inside and **on** the unit circle, except at $x=-1$. This follows trivially from the generalised alternating test. So you can indeed plug in $x=1$. No arguing is needed.

Comment: @Leg the OP states "I was recently working on a homework problem where I was given to find if [the series] converges." Not sure if using consequences of properties of power series combined with the generalized alternating test counts as common knowledge then. Again, I do not claim the answer is incorrect.